# Tesseract can't recognize image after Clearing image incomprehensibly

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract

I want to ocr two-digit-image after erasing right number for good accuracy. 
Example) [Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA2WK.png), [Modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKrPn.png)

The image is PNG file(52*26px) and background color is (192,192,192,255) and color of each digit is different.

But amazingly after erasig right number, tesseract cannot recognize the number.

Result:

```
original:60
left:
```

---

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract.pytesseract import *

im=Image.open('NA2WK.png')

#calculate far left xpos of color
color={}
for i in range(52):
    for j in range(26):
        if im.load()[i,j]!=(192,192,192,255):
            if color.get(im.load()[i,j])==None:
                color[im.load()[i,j]]=9999
            if i<color[im.load()[i,j]]: 
                color[im.load()[i,j]]=i

#get color of left character
if color.values()[0]<color.values()[1]:
    left=color.keys()[0]
    right=color.keys()[1]
else:
    left=color.keys()[1]
    right=color.keys()[0]   

#left processing
imleft=Image.open('test.png')
pix=imleft.load()
for i in range(52):
    for j in range(26):
        if pix[i,j]==(192,192,192,255) or pix[i,j]==right:
            pix[i,j]=(255,255,255,255)
        else:
            pix[i,j]=(0,0,0,255)

print('original:'+image_to_string(im))
print('left:'+image_to_string(imleft))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract performs a connected component analysis internally. It does try to group blocks of text together and might be causing an issue due to lack of too many characters within the page. There is page segmentation mode wherein you can ask tesseract to treat the image as a single character. Try this approach it may give you the required results.